# display all departments and all employees

Tags: sql

if there :

(department) table: (id,name)

(employee) table  : (id,dept_id,name)

how to show every department (id,name), then all employees (id,name) in this department under its department.

I'd like it as SQL statment

Comment: You'll be wanting a JOIN clause in your SELECT statement. There are many places you can read about this.

Comment: You have tags for both MySQL and Oracle. Which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use JOIN

I believe it's something like this:

```
SELECT department.id, department.name, employee.id, employee.name
FROM department
LEFT JOIN employee
ON department.id=employee.dept_id
ORDER BY department.id
```

Comment: You don't have any aggregate functions, why do you need `GROUP BY`?

Comment: Removed `group by` from first line, since that's not the part of answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since all employees must be present under a particular department at any time, you can do a `inner join` on both the table with `dept_id` like

```
SELECT dept.id, dept.name, emp.id, emp.name
FROM department dept
JOIN employee emp
ON dept.id=emp.dept_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this

```
SELECT D.ID,D.Name,E.ID,E.Name
FROM Department D Left JOIN Employee E ON E.dept_id = D.Id
```